# Volley throwing AuthFailureError (403- Forbidden) com.android.volley.AuthFailureError in Android

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, android-volley

I'm developing an app that have function to update data or edit data from editText. In edit text have data from user object but if user wants to edit one of any editText or change user can change that data and call next api button to update data but api throw this error **volley authentication failure error**

There is a screen that get users data in edittext when pass data direct to API for add data to api
same api works amazing on **POSTMAN** but when same api call in android that throw Authication failure error.
Here is Debug response

[image: Postman Respones]

[image: Android response here]

**NetworkAPICall.kt**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import com.android.volley.*
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import com.softnoesis.maxotexmart.login.LoginActivity
import com.softnoesis.maxotexmart.utils.AppPreference
import com.softnoesis.maxotexmart.utils.CommonUtils
import com.softnoesis.maxotexmart.utils.Constant.Companion.NETWORK_API_CALL
import com.softnoesis.maxotexmart.utils.Constant.Companion.TAG
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.lang.reflect.Type

class NetworkAPICall {
    fun CallApplicationWS(mContext: Activity?, NetworkAPICallModel: NetworkAPICallModel,
                          NetworkAPIResponseCallback: NetworkAPIResponseCallback?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "$NETWORK_API_CALL --> CallApplicationWS")
        if (NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().isNetworkAvailable(mContext!!)) try {
            if (!NetworkAPICallModel.isShowProgress())
                NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().showProgress(mContext)
            val RequestQueue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext)
            val StringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(NetworkAPICallModel.getRequest_type(),
                NetworkAPICallModel.getApiURL(), Response.Listener<String?> { response ->
                Log.i(TAG, "$NETWORK_API_CALL --> " +
                        "CallApplicationWS --> response")
                try{
                    NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().hideProgress()
                    if(NetworkAPICallModel.getParserType() != null) {
                        val `object`: Any = Gson().fromJson(response, NetworkAPICallModel.getParserType())
                        NetworkAPICallModel.setResponseObject(`object`)
                    }
                    NetworkAPIResponseCallback?.onSuccessResponse(JSONObject(response), NetworkAPICallModel)
                } catch(jsonException: Exception) {
                    NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().hideProgress()
                    Log.i(TAG, "$NETWORK_API_CALL --> CallApplicationWS --> response --> ${jsonException.message}")
                    try{
                        NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().hideProgress()
                        /*if(NetworkAPIResponseCallback != null) {
                                NetworkAPIResponseCallback.onSuccessResponse(new JSONObject(response), NetworkAPICallModel);
                          }*/
                    }catch (e: Exception) {
                        NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().hideProgress()
                        Log.i(TAG, "$NETWORK_API_CALL --> CallApplicationWS --> response --> ${e.message}")
                    }
                }
            },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().hideProgress()
                    Log.i(TAG, "$NETWORK_API_CALL --> CallApplicationWS --> error --> ${error.message}")
                    val response: NetworkResponse = error.networkResponse
                    if (error is ServerError) {
                        try {
                            val intent = Intent(mContext, LoginActivity::class.java)
                            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            mContext.startActivity(intent)
                        } catch (e1: Exception) {
                            NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().hideProgress()
                            Log.i(TAG, "$NETWORK_API_CALL --> CallApplicationWS --> error --> ${e1.message}")
                        }
                    }
                    CommonUtils().hideProgress()
                    CommonUtils().showDialog(
                        mContext,
                        """
                                            Something went wrong! Please try again later!
                                            If problem still persist, please drop mail at support@.com
                                            """.trimIndent()
                    ).show()
            }) {
                override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    var params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                    val type: Type = object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.type
                    params = Gson().fromJson(NetworkAPICallModel.getJsonObjectRequest().toString(), type)
                    return params
                }

                override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
//                     headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + jetEncryptor.getJwtkey());
                    if (AppPreference(mContext).isUserLogin()) {
                        params["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + AppPreference(mContext).getToken()
                    }
                    return params
                }
            }
            RequestQueue.add(StringRequest)
            StringRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().hideProgress()
            Log.i(TAG, "$NETWORK_API_CALL --> CallApplicationWS -->${e.message}")
        } else {
            NetworkAPICallModel.getCommonUtils().hideProgress()
            CommonUtils().showDialog(mContext, "Please check you internet connection").show()
        }
    }
}
```

The below code is dummy parameter going to pass through network call

```
try {
val mJsObjParam = JSONObject()
        mJsObjParam.put("company_name", userData1.user?.companyName ?: ""   )
        mJsObjParam.put("owner_name", userData1.user?.ownerName ?: "")
        mJsObjParam.put("owner_phone", userData1.user?.phone ?: "")
        mJsObjParam.put("owner_whatsapp_number", userData1.user?.ownerWhatsappNumber ?: "")
        mJsObjParam.put("address", userData1.user?.address ?: "")
val parserType = object : TypeToken<EditUserResponse?>() {}.type
        val networkAPICallModel = NetworkAPICallModel(
            APIConstants.EDIT_USER_URL,
            APIConstants.POST_REQUEST,
            mJsObjParam
        )
        networkAPICallModel.setParserType(parserType)
        mNetworkAPICall!!.CallApplicationWS(mContext as Activity?, networkAPICallModel, this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        mCommonUtils?.hideProgress()
        Log.i(
            Constant.TAG,
            "${Constant.USER_PRESENTER} --> addUser --> Exception --> ${e.printStackTrace()}"
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems Authentication error, code: 401, you need to check token or accessToken if you are using for your api call.

Here is the code for api call which is taking some token for further work using volley:

```
    fun updateAccessToken(): String {
    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    binding.layoutRefresh.visibility = View.GONE
    var refreshToken = ""
    baseUrl = "${
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            "https://debug.domainName.in/"
        } else {
            "https://prod.domainName.in/"
        }
    }"
    if (Utility.isNetworkAvailable(requireContext())) {
        var responseToken: okhttp3.Response
        val context = (AppApplicationClass).appContext
        var requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
        val jsonBody = JSONObject()
        jsonBody.put("contact_number", AppFlowModulePreference.getMobileNumber())
        val url =
            baseUrl + "mobile-app/app-user-tokens/"
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val jsonObjReq = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Method.POST, url, jsonBody,
            com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
                (response)
                //responseToken = response
                var jsobjectMeta: JSONObject =
                    response.getJSONObject(context.resources.getString(R.string.meta))
                var status =
                    jsobjectMeta.getString(context.resources.getString(R.string.status_api_success))
                if (status.equals("200")) {
                  //use response as per your requirement.
                }
            },

            com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                VolleyLog.e(HomeActivity.TAG, "/post request fail! Error: ${error.message}")
            }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers.put(
                    context.resources.getString(R.string.authorization),
                    context.resources.getString(R.string.token_space) + AppFlowModulePreference.getAccessTokenForLoanFlow()
                )
                return headers
            }
        }

        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(
            DefaultRetryPolicy(
                valuePolicyIntiIimeOut,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
            )
        )
        requestQueue?.add(jsonObjReq)
    } else {
        //internetNotWorking UI handling action
    }
    return refreshToken
}
```

Comment: This is clearly 403 error of forbidden error